# Create a Table from a SQL Query with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have 3 tables that I want to join in a single table `collaborator` with this Sql query :

```
select * from (
select user.id, Project.id, Task.id
inner join Project on user.join_key = Project.join_key
inner join  Task  on task.join_key = = Project.join_key
) collaborator
```

And I can't seem to find How to.
I can use this also :

```
CREATE TABLE Collaborator AS
SELECT user.id, Project.id, Task.id
FROM Project p, Task t, User u
inner join Project on user.join_key = Project.join_key
inner join  Task  on task.join_key = = Project.join_key.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the table

Collaborator

```
CREATE TABLE `Collaborator` (
  `USER_id` int(11),
 `PROJECT_id` int(11),
 `TASK_id` int(11)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And then excecute the insert

```
INSERT INTO Collaborator 
SELECT user.id, Project.id, Task.id
FROM Project p, Task t, User u
inner join Project on user.join_key = Project.join_key
inner join  Task  on task.join_key = = Project.join_key
```

Comment: the only thing I would suggest is to explicitly identify columns on insert the lazy style like this can lead to issues when/if columns change on the table or in the select.  INSERT INTO Collaborator (User_id, Project_id, Task_id)